# $\max\{c^Tx:Ax\le b,x\ge 0\}=+\infty$ iif it exists $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $\max \{x_j:Ax\le b, x\ge 0\}=+\infty$

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Show a vector $\vec c$ exists such that $\max\{c^Tx:Ax\le b,x\ge 0\}=+\infty$ if and only if it exists $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $\max \{x_j:Ax\le b, x\ge 0\}=+\infty$

**I'm only asking for a hint or criticize of my proof attempt**

Broadly speaking, I think I have to show that a vector tends to infinity when maximizing the whole program iif the the objective function tends to infinity when maximizing under the constraints (I'm not sure about this part)

I started with assuming that it exists $x_j$ such that $\max \{x_j:Ax\le b, x\ge 0\}=+\infty$

for instance

\begin{cases}
\max & x_1\\
&-x_1 &\le -1\\
&x_1&\ge 0 
\end{cases}

then **$Ax$** must be negative and **$b$** positive then $\forall c^T$ such that $c^Tx\ge0$, $\max \{c^Tx:Ax\le b, x\ge 0\}=+\infty$, **but is it a** rigorous and strict proof?

I then have to prove the revert

Let's assume that it exists $c^Tx$ such that $\max \{c^Tx:Ax\le b, x\ge 0\}=+\infty$

Comment: Going from the second statement to the first is trivial, because given such a $j$, you just pick $c=e_j$ (the $j$th unit vector) and you're done. It is going from the first statement to the second that is the real challenge.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes, indeed. Do you have any hints to start with?